# Logic: Find a sentence that satisfies certain properties

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

1) Let $L=\{R\}$ be a language with $R$ a binary function symbol. Find a sentence $\phi$ which is true in $N_2 = (\mathbb{N}^*, |)$, where $|$ is the divisibility relation, but false in $(P_{fin}(\mathbb{N}), \subseteq)$, where $P_{fin}(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of (possibly empty) finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and $\mathbb{N}^*$ is the set of non-zero natural numbers.

**Attempt at the solution**: I tried many combinations of $\forall x\exists y$ but I just couldn't get a solution... Could someone please give me a hint?

2) Let $L = \{<\}$. Find a sentence $\phi$ which is true in $(\mathbb{Q}, <)$ but false in $(\mathbb{Z},<)$.

**Attempt at the solution**: I think what makes $\mathbb{Q}$ different from $\mathbb{Z}$ is that the former is a set of fractions. So we should focus on this property. However, I can't assume something like x/y, because we are not given any binary function symbol to consider division...

Comment: Hint for 2), the rational number are dense, i.e. there is always a rational number in between any two rational numbers.

Comment: Excelente! Thanks

Comment: I hate to say that there's only one solution to a problem. But apart from your hint, I don't really see any other way to construct such sentence using only symbolic logic (maybe combined in a very complicated way), but not using some non-trivial property of the structure (like density of the ration field).

Answer (score 2):

The second one is answered in a comment. Let me do the first one.

I am assuming that your first order logic has equality; if it does not, define $x = y$ as a shorthand for $xRy \land yRx$. (Note that in both your structures, this is the same as equality.)

Define
$$
\phi = \forall x \exists y \exists z((yRx \land zRx \land y \neq z \land x \neq y \land x \neq z ) \to \exists w(wRx \land w \neq y \land w \neq z \land w \neq x)).
$$
That is, for each $x$, if there are $y,z$ in the $R$-relation to $x$, and these three are all distinct, then there is a fourth (distinct) $w$ which is also in the $R$-relation $x$. This sentence is false in the divisibility structure: $4$ only has $2$ and $1$ strictly dividing it. However, it is true in the subset structure: if $w$ has two distinct strict subsets, it has at least two elements $a,b$; hence it has at least *three* distinct strict subsets, namely $\{a\},\{b\},\emptyset$.

Comment: Q1) the question asks for the opposite, true in divisibility and false for the subset structure. Q2) Assume the question asks for the opposite, could you tell me the way you think about such problem?

Comment: @HuyTruong. Visualize  a transitive reflexive  binary relation $R$  as a  tree-like or root-like structure, with  a line  going upward from $x$ to $y$ if $xRy$ and $x\ne y$ . Look for a sub-structure found in one structure but not in the other. E.g $4$ has exactly $3$ divisors but no set has exactly $3$ subsets. Similarly,in Q2, the order on $\mathbb Q$ is order-dense (or "order-dense in itself"),  but there is no $ x\in \mathbb N$ such that $1<x<2.$

Comment: @HuyTruong, so use $\neg\phi$ instead of $\phi$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Thanks to your hint, I was able to come up an example on my own. Could you help me exam if this works: $\exists x \exists y (yRx \rightarrow \exists z(z\ne x \wedge z\ne y \wedge zRx)$. That is, in the divisibility structure, there is a number that has 3 divisors but in the subset structure, no such thing exists as the size of every finite subset has $2^n$ subsets.

Comment: @HuyTruong, your sentence is true in both structures. Presumably, you meant to write $\forall x \forall y$ at the start of the sentence. Then it is actually false in both structures; it does not hold for $x = y = 1$ or $x = y = \emptyset$ respectively.